# Easiest way to import the modules from parent folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have my folder setup as such.

```
Desktop/project1/
```

Inside project1, I have the main.py where I have all my functions stored, as well as a folder for each instance. So it looks like this.

```
Desktop/project1/main.py
Desktop/project1/user1/
Desktop/project1/user2/
```

and inside the user folders, i have:

```
Desktop/project1/user1/user1.py
Desktop/project1/user2/user2.py
```

I need to be able to import and use the functions from main.py in each user.py folder inside the folder for that user. Any Idea how to do this easily?

I am using Pycharm, and when I start typing this in, it auto fills it for me, like it can see both the main.py, as well as the functions inside it, but then when I run the program I get an error.

```
from main import function1

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

Thanks

Comment: In this case, changing the working directory to `project1` would be enough.

Comment: @PeterWood So when I closed my pycharm project and opened the project from user1 folder with only the user1.py file, now the import statement is red underlined, and its not auto filling it, and it still doesnt work.

Comment: But that's not what I said.

Comment: Nvm, I think i got it figured out. When I went into edit configurations from pycharm, and changed the working directory to that, it worked.  Although, I plan on running this user1.py file from command line. Will that still work, will i just need to cd into that folder before running it? Thank you @PeterWood.

Comment: Yes. But you can also use relative imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the directory's path to your `sys.path` using

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'path\to\dir')
```

After that you can normally import the file.
You can retrieve the parent directory's path using `pathlib`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create an empty file `__init__.py` in your module directory. `__init__` can detect your custom python modules